# Do PayPal keep their cut on cancelled payments?

Tags: paypal

Say I have two email addresses X and Y. I normally use X and keep Y for more private uses, such as PayPal. Somebody mistakenly sent me a payment to the X email address. I could tell them to cancel the payment, but I'm afraid that if they did so PayPal would still keep their cut.

If they do, I'd *very* much rather avoid that and sign up with the X email address and just pay something the amount of money received precisely, something that's not too hard nowadays thanks to the "Pay what you want" offers.

So: does PayPal keep the cut on a cancelled payment?

The help center does not answer this question in [the relevant support article.](https://www.paypal.com/helpcenter/main.jsp;jsessionid=LSyqTpJFTHk9cQLV1T0D68ph7n11TJP2LyHn2mFDPwwR2wtrns2d!-831548207?locale=en_US&_dyncharset=UTF-8&countrycode=US&cmd=_help&serverInstance=9004&t=solutionTab&ft=searchTab&ps=solutionPanels&solutionId=10532&isSrch=Yes)

Answer (score 1):

If you refunded the payment, rather than cancelling it, the fees are also refunded provided the payment was for goods or services.

> You can partially or fully refund a buyer within 60 days of receiving
>   their payment. Refunds are available only for transactions involving
>   the purchase of goods and services.
>
> When issuing a full refund, your original transaction fee is credited
>   to you. When issuing a partial refund, a portion of the fee is
>   credited to you.

Source: [PayPal](https://www.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=xpt/Marketing/bizui/SendRefund-outside)

Answer (score 0):

An example [here](https://www.paypal.com/gb/selfhelp/article/common-questions-about-issuing-refunds-faq3214/10):

> Example:
>
> - A buyer sends £100 to a seller
> - Assuming the seller is on the standard fee rate (3.4% plus 20p), the seller receives £96.40 into their PayPal account
> - The seller later decides to issue a full refund to the buyer
> - During the refund, PayPal credits the merchant £3.40
> - The buyer receives a full refund of £100